# Restore Log and Differential Backups Simultaneously in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup, restore, ssms

I have the full backup of a database, also one differential backup and one log backup. Is it possible to restore this 3 backups together? SSMS lets only full backup and only one of them. Is there a way to restore both? It's okay to show the way in t-sql too.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try looking here for restores with NORECOVERY, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#restoring_full_n_differential_db_backups

Comment: Are you sure the log backup was taken after the diff, and that the diff is based on that specific full backup? (I only ask because in a disaster people will scramble to find these things on archives or wherever and they sometimes don't have anything to do with each other.)

Comment: Yes, the order is the same. But the thing is I am studying not in a disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tsql. Also, highly recommend to use [sp_restoregene](https://paulbrewer.wordpress.com/sp_restoregene/). This will generate restore commands for you which you can just execute .